# Show $\rho_j =\sum^\infty_{k=1} \alpha_{jk} \epsilon_k$ is a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\alpha_{jk}$ be numbers for $j,k \geq 1$ such that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_{jk}|^2 <\infty$$

Define $T: l^2 \to l^2$ as follows.

If $x=(\epsilon_j)$, $y=(\rho_j)$ and $tx=y$ then $$\rho_j =\sum^\infty_{k=1} \alpha_{jk} \epsilon_k$$

I want to show that $T$ is a compact operator.

> To show an operator is compact, what do you have to show?
>   I have the proof (below) but I don't not understand it
>   Let $a_j=(\bar\alpha_{jk}) \in l^2$
>
> Where does $\bar\alpha_{jk}$ come from?

Then $Tx=\langle x,a_j \rangle$

> Where does this come from?

Then we define $T_n (\langle  x, a \rangle , ..., \langle x , a_n \langle, 0, 0,..)$

Then $T_n:l^2 \to l^2$ is compact

> If we have shown that it is compact why do we have to do the below?

$||(T-T_n)x||^2 =\sum_{j \geq n} | \langle x , a_j \langle|^2 \leq ||x||^2 \sum_{j >n} ||a_j||^2$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j \geq n} \sum_k |\alpha_{jk}|^2 =0$

> Where does this come from?

Comment: It is shown that $A$ is a limit of finite rank operators. In a Hilbert space this is equivalent to being compact.

Comment: @petermelech   What is the limit of finite rank operators?

Comment: It is shown that $T$ is the limit of the operators $T_n$ and $\dim ran T_n \leq n<\infty$ i.e. $T_n$ are finite rank operators, besides in line 4 isn´t it $Tx=y$ and in line 10 $Tx=(<x,a_j>)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ ?, this works with $a_j=(\overline{\alpha_{jk}}) $ because the inner product is conjugate linear in the second factor

Comment: @petermelech that is how it is defined in the solutions I have been given by my lecturer

Comment: @petermelech do you have a better proof?

Comment: No the proof is excellent. There are just some little typos/inaccuracies, like the two mentioned and in line 12 $T_nx=(<x,a_1>,...,<x,a_n>,0,...)$. This is a finite rank operator (these are compact by Heine Borel), and then it is shown $T$ is the limit of the $T_n$ s . For the background I´d recommend e.g.Brezis "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" Corollary 6.2.

Comment: @petermelech so does showing that T is the limit of $T_n s$ mean that T is compact?

Comment: @petermelech I usually would not spam anyone like this but could you please look at my other question?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769548/show-the-operator-s-defined-by-sa-n-bigg-frac35-biggn-a-n-is-bound                                                    Its is just that my exam is in a couple of days time and I am really struggling with this module, had to self teach it because I just can not understand the lecturer and he does not reply to students via email

Comment: Yes! This is proven in the Corollary I cited.https://www.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/lecturers/ma/milen/Brezis_FA_PDE.pdf

Comment: OK. I´ll have a look at it later. If You have to self teach this I´ll recommend Brezi´s book again. (the pdf is free online)

Comment: @petermelech thank you. Thank you for the link.

Comment: In the question, why do we define $T_n x$ using inner products? How do we define in general the finite rank operator?

Comment: $Tx=(<x,a_j>)_{j=1}^{\infty}=(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_{jk}\epsilon_k)_{j=1}^{ \infty}$ it´s just another way to write it down, finite rank operators are those with a finite dimensional range and these are by Heine Borel´s theorem compact

Comment: I understand, thank you:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39221/discussion-between-al-jabra-and-peter-melech).