# Show the operator $S$ defined by $(Sa)_n=\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^n a_n$ is bounded on $l^2$ and find the operator norm. Is $S$ is invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis

Define the operator $S: l^2 \to l^2$ by 
$$(Sa)_n=\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^n a_n$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ an $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is how we show it is bounded. 
$$||S(a)||^2_{l^2}=\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^2 a_1^2 +\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^4 a_2^2 + \bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^6 a_3^2 +..$$
$$\leq \bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^2 ||a||^2 _{l^2}$$

Hence $$||S(a)||_{l^2} \leq \bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)||a||_{l^2}$$
So $S$ is a bounded linear operator on $l^2$

> Where do the powers $2,4$ and $6$ come from?

Now we find the operator norm.

> To do this why do we let $S$ act on $e=(1,0,0,0,..)$?

From this we can clearly see that $$||S(e)||_{l^2}=\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg) ||e||_{l^2}$$

Such that the norm of the operator $S$,  $$||S||=\frac{3}{5}$$

If we want to find out if $S$ is invertible, then we check to seeif $$S^{-1} (b)_n=\bigg(\frac{5}{3}\bigg)^n (a)_n$$

> Why do we choose $a=(1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},..)$?

Comment: $||Sa||_{\ell^2}^2=\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty}|(Sa)_n|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty}(\frac{3}{5})^{2n}a_n^2$.For the inverse operator $(S^{-1}b)_n=(\frac{5}{3})^nb_n$ check for example for $a \in \ell^2$ if $S^{-1}a \in \ell^2$?

Comment: So $a $ could be anything in $l^2$?

Comment: @petermelech if you write what you said as a comment as an answer, I will be happy to select you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just compute $||Sa||_{\ell^2}^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(Sa)_n|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3}{5})^{2n}a_n^2$. (This is where the powers 2,4,6,... come from).
If $S:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ was invertible the inverse operator would have to be of the form

$(S^{-1}b)_n=(\frac{5}{3})^nb_n$

but this isn´t bounded and if You pick $a=(1,\frac{1}{2},...)\in \ell^2$
(a little bit lucky)
then even $S^{-1}a\notin \ell^2$, because

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{3})^{2n}\frac{1}{n^2}=\infty$.

This is clear from $(\frac{5}{3})^{2n}\frac{1}{n^2}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}\infty$

Comment: Same with the other question, if you write it up, ill accept you. And I also have one other question about the previous question and I cant ask you in those comments as it sends me to chat.

Comment: If you are in the $l^2$ space, should it not be $||Sa||^2 _{l^2}=\sqrt{\sum^\infty _{n=1} |(Sa)_n|^2}$?

Comment: That´s why the square is on the left side $||Sa||_{\ell^2}=\sqrt{\sum_n |(Sa)_n|^2}$. Squaring both sides gives the equation given.

Comment: oh of course, I think I have spent to much time on functional and i am confusing myself. But it is a good thing, clarity usually follows confusion

Comment: That´s right :-)